# Do Activities get destroyed and recreated in Android during lifecycle events? Or do they simply get “re-attached”?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Let us consider the following example subclass of an `Activity`

```
public class CustomActivity extends Activity
{
    private int myIntVar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom);

        if (myIntVar == 0)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int    min  = 1;
            int    max  = 100;

            myIntVar =  rand.nextInt((max+1) - min) + min;
        }
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

According to the official documentation for the [Android lifecycle methods](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

The method `onSaveInstanceState(...)` is called to allow the application time to save its current state before being put into the background. But what happens to the object of `CustomActivity` that is currently loaded in memory? Does it also get created and destroyed alongside the lifecycle events? Or is it preserved perpetually in memory (as long as the application is still active - even if it's in the background) and it will simply be "re-attached" when the time comes?

In other words, throughout an Android applications entire lifespan (from the user opening it initially, to it being closed after the user swipes it away in the task-manager/menu screen) Will `myIntVar` only be set once, or multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it also get created and destroyed alongside the lifecycle events?

Yes.

> Or is it preserved perpetually in memory (as long as the application is still active - even if it's in the background) and it will simply be "re-attached" when the time comes?

No.

> Will myIntVar only be set once, or multiple times?

For any given `CustomActivity` instance, once. Across all `CustomActivity` instances, multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. But doesn't your first and third answer contradict each other? If the actual class instance itself is getting created and destroyed alongside lifecycle events, how can your claim of *"For any given `CustomActivity` instance, once"* be valid?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: "But doesn't your first and third answer contradict each other?" -- no. "how can your claim of "For any given CustomActivity instance, once" be valid?" -- something calls `startActivity()` for `CustomActivity`. An instance of `CustomActivity` gets created, and `myIntVar` is set. The device then undergoes a configuration change. Android creates **another instance of `CustomActivity`**. The original instance is discarded. The **new** instance of `CustomActivity` has `myIntVar` set. So, for any given `CustomActivity` instance, `myIntVar` is set once.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As a side note, during low memory circumstances, do you know whether or not Android will kill my app in its entirety? Or does it start dismantling my app by unloading one activity at a time?

Comment: @AlanSTACK: Android [terminates your process](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html).